# array filtering does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and I wanna filter them based on their size, color and collar.

everything works as expected whenever I uncheck a checkbox but when I re-check it again it brings back unwanted objects.

```js
var DATABASE = [
    {id:0o1, size: "XL",  color:"red",    collar: "v-neck"},
    {id:0o2, size: "S",   color:"blue",   collar: "regular"},
    {id:0o3, size: "XXL", color:"red",    collar: "scoop"},
    {id:0o4, size: "L",   color:"green",  collar: "v-neck"},
    {id:0o5, size: "XL",  color:"blue",   collar: "turtle-neck"},
    {id:0o6, size: "L",   color:"red",    collar: "v-neck"}
];


window.onload = function () {

    var vNeckCollarCheckbox = document.querySelector('#vneck-collar-checkbox');
    var xlSizeCheckbox = document.querySelector('#xl-size-checkbox');
    var redColorCheckbox = document.querySelector('#red-color-checkbox');

    var div = document.querySelector('div');


    var DB = DATABASE;


    function filterByVneckCollar() {
        let vNeckCollar = DATABASE.filter(function (item) {
            return item.collar === "v-neck";
        });
        if(!vNeckCollarCheckbox.checked){
            DB = DB.filter(function (i) {
                return vNeckCollar.indexOf(i) < 0;
            });
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }
        else{
            DB = DB.concat(vNeckCollar);
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }
    }

    function filterByXlSize() {
        let xlSize = DATABASE.filter(function (item) {
            return item.size === "XL";
        });
        if(!xlSizeCheckbox.checked){
            DB = DB.filter(function (i) {
                return xlSize.indexOf(i) < 0;
            });
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }
        else{
            DB = DB.concat(xlSize);
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }
    }

    function filterByRedColor() {
        let redColor = DATABASE.filter(function (item) {
            return item.color === "red";
        });
        if(!redColorCheckbox.checked){
            DB = DB.filter(function (i) {
                return redColor.indexOf(i) < 0;
            });
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }
        else{
            DB = DB.concat(redColor);
            div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);
        }

    }


    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DB);

    vNeckCollarCheckbox.addEventListener('change', filterByVneckCollar);
    xlSizeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', filterByXlSize);
    redColorCheckbox.addEventListener('change', filterByRedColor);

};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#">

    <input type="checkbox" id="vneck-collar-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="vneck-collar-checkbox">V-neck collar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="xl-size-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="xl-size-checkbox">XL size</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="red-color-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="red-color-checkbox">Red color</label>

</form>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this:

1. uncheck "red color"
2. uncheck "XL size"
3. check "XL size"

You would see object containing "color: red" appears.

I know that the problem is in **DB = DB.concat(xxxxx);** of else{} statement but I don't know how to achieve desired output.

any other solution/concept to achieve this sort of filter is appreciated.

Comment: Would you create jsfiddle for this

Comment: var DB = DATABASE is a bit misleading. Name it 'selection' etc. to make the distinction clear.

Comment: @sajad this seems bit confusing, what you want to achieve, would you explain a bit more about what you need to filter in database with input checkboxes

Comment: @sajad, you can do this by writing single filter function and inside that you can check all 3 cases at once

Comment: @sajad, is my answer helpful?

Comment: @ParagBhayani your answer was perfect, thank you.

Comment: I'll do bro as soon as my reputation become 15 (stack-overflow does not allow me to upvote yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter on `DATABASE` once with the combination of rules you need.

I've put a JSDoc on the more complicated function for you, which I made generic so can be used for other things too

```
/**
 * @callback FilterRuleTest
 * @param {Object} obj The target Object
 * @returns {Boolean} Whether obj passed the test
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} FilterRule
 * @property {String} [key] A property key to find on the target
 * @property {String} [value] The value assigned to the key of the target
 * @property {FilterRuleTest} [test] A function to run on target, return bool
 */

/** Filters an Array of Objects
 * @param {[Object]} arrayOfObjects The Array of Objects to filter
 * @param {[FilterRule]} arrayOfRules The Array of Objects to filter with
 * @param {Boolean} [invert] Return the opposite of the rules
 * @param {Boolean} [emptyRulePasses] Default behaviour of empty rule
 * @returns {[Object]} The filtered result
 */
function objFilter(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfRules, invert = false, emptyRulePasses = false) {
    return arrayOfObjects.filter(obj => {
        return invert !== arrayOfRules.every(rule => {
            if ('key' in rule) {
                if ('value' in rule)
                    return obj[rule.key] === obj[rule.value];
                return rule.key in obj;
            }
            if ('test' in rule) {
                return rule.test(obj);
            }
            return emptyRulePasses;
        });
    });
}

function createFilterRules(collar, size, color) {
    let rules = [];
    if (collar) rules.push({key: 'collar', value: collar});
    if (size) rules.push({key: 'size', value: size});
    if (color) rules.push({key: 'color', value: color});
    return rules;
}

const vNeckCollarCheckbox = document.querySelector('#vneck-collar-checkbox');
const xlSizeCheckbox = document.querySelector('#xl-size-checkbox');
const redColorCheckbox = document.querySelector('#red-color-checkbox');
const div = document.querySelector('div');

function filterClothes(db) {
    return objFilter(
        db,
        createFilterRules(
            vNeckCollarCheckbox.checked ? 'v-neck' : null,
            xlSizeCheckbox.checked ? 'XL' : null,
            redColorCheckbox.checked ? 'red' : null
        )
    );
}

function clothesHandle() {
    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(filterClothes(DATABASE));
}

vNeckCollarCheckbox.addEventListener('change', clothesHandle);
xlSizeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', clothesHandle);
redColorCheckbox.addEventListener('change', clothesHandle);
```

Comment: @ParagBhayani fixed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your filter functions start with the complete set and filter out based on only one of the checkbox values.

Instead create a one-for-all filter.

You can also write the filter condition in a concise way: either the checkbox is set, or you apply a condition. This can be expressed with the boolean `||` operator.

Finally, I would suggest to use the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event instead of the `load` event, as it fires sooner while still guaranteeing the DOM elements are accessible.

```js
var DATABASE = [
    {id:0o1, size: "XL",  color:"red",    collar: "v-neck"},
    {id:0o2, size: "S",   color:"blue",   collar: "regular"},
    {id:0o3, size: "XXL", color:"red",    collar: "scoop"},
    {id:0o4, size: "L",   color:"green",  collar: "v-neck"},
    {id:0o5, size: "XL",  color:"blue",   collar: "turtle-neck"},
    {id:0o6, size: "L",   color:"red",    collar: "v-neck"}
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var vNeckCollarCheckbox = document.querySelector('#vneck-collar-checkbox');
    var xlSizeCheckbox = document.querySelector('#xl-size-checkbox');
    var redColorCheckbox = document.querySelector('#red-color-checkbox');
    var div = document.querySelector('div');

    function applyFilter() {
        div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(DATABASE.filter(function (item) {
            return (vNeckCollarCheckbox.checked || item.collar !== "v-neck") &&
                   (xlSizeCheckbox.checked      || item.size !== "XL") &&
                   (redColorCheckbox.checked    || item.color !== "red");
        }));
    }

    vNeckCollarCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
    xlSizeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
    redColorCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilter);
    
    applyFilter();
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <input type="checkbox" id="vneck-collar-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="vneck-collar-checkbox">V-neck collar</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="xl-size-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="xl-size-checkbox">XL size</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="red-color-checkbox" checked>
    <label for="red-color-checkbox">Red color</label>
</form>
<div></div>
```

Comment: It worked well bro except whenever I want to filter based on one object property twice. ex: (xlSizeCheckbox.checked      || item.size !== "XL") && (lSizeCheckbox.checked      || item.size !== "L"); it gives me an empty array

Comment: Please check the console, because as you write it here you have an `x` missing in the second occurrence of the name of the checkbox. It should be ***x**lSizeCheckbox*. When I try with that, I get results.

Comment: Note also that you can write such a "combined" condition like this as well, which is easier to extend: `(xlSizeCheckbox.checked || ["XL", "L"].indexOf(item.size) === -1)`.

Comment: check this fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sabbasi/4noxjsy0/). try checking v-neck and scoop neck checkboxes. You would see an empty array.

Comment: But you have put a negation (`!`) before every checkbox condition. That of course makes the conditions completely different. If your logic is that you only show a certain item when the corresponding checkbox is checked, but apply the filter when it is not checked, then you should not add the `!` like you have done.

Comment: Did you try without the `!`? It works much better then.

Comment: I tried without (!) and it just worked. Thank you so much

Comment: Combined condition helped a lot, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: No, your answer is totally right but after 9 months learning more about JS, I believe Paul's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes each contribute an individual part to a global filter. If you uncheck a checkbox, 1. your global filter is modified and 2. your selected data is the result of filtering your database with the modified filter.

Regarding your 'global' filter: You could implement it as a single Array.filter() callback which returns true if the given element should be filtered according to *any* checkbox, or you could chain calls to Array.filter() each having a callback filtering elements according to a single checkbox.

No concatenation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the base array by all properties, each time one of the filters changes.

```
function applyFilters(){

    curr_db = DB;

    if ( ! vNeckCollarCheckbox.checked) {
        curr_db = filterByVneckCollar(curr_db);
    }
    if ( ! xlSizeCheckbox.checked) {
        curr_db = filterByXlSize(curr_db);
    }
    if ( ! redColorCheckbox.checked) {
        curr_db = filterByRedColor(curr_db);
    }

    div.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(curr_db);
}

vNeckCollarCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilters);
xlSizeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilters);
redColorCheckbox.addEventListener('change', applyFilters);
```

And then use the filter functions to remove the undesired items only.

```
function filterByRedColor(curr_db) {
    return curr_db.filter(function(){
        return item.color != "red";
    });
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a one filter function can solve this issue for you, whenever you filter item by item check whether every condition of checkbox is satisfied by your filter .. if yes then and then accept it by returning true in the filter function... otherwise returning false for that item will not show that item in the selection database... I hope this clarifies your doubt...

```
var selection = [];

var vNeckCollarCheckbox = document.querySelector('#vneck-collar-checkbox').checked;
var xlSizeCheckbox = document.querySelector('#xl-size-checkbox').checked;
var redColorCheckbox = document.querySelector('#red-color-checkbox').checked;

selection = DATABASE.filter(function (item) {
    // Write all condition which will fail for the current data here and return false, every condition passes it will send true by default at the end
    if(vNeckCollarCheckbox) {
        if(item.collar != "v-neck") {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(xlSizeCheckbox) {
        if(item.size != "XL") {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(redColorCheckbox) {
        if(item.color != "red") {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```